# Code sample for an OpenDNP3 library problem: master always polling the outstation

Tags: c#, version, communication, dnp3, opendnp3

I run the code sample that is included on GitHub for [GitHub OpenDNP3](https://github.com/dnp3/opendnp3) with the most recent [NuGet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet) package of this library and the sample seems to do not work as expected.

I start the outstation. Then I start the master. The result of the master is constantly polling the outstation. It never stops. I thought it could do one integrity poll (or not) and wait for me to press a key, but I can't. The screen is always dumping the state of the outstation.

Is OpenDNP3 working properly and/or is the sample bugged?

[image: Output of master]

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."* (it covers terminal output as well) ) and [do](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72801993/edit) the right thing.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, Thanks a lot Peter for the information. Without knowging exactly that, I usually try to use text instead of image for the same reasons explained. In this case, I intentionaly chosen to use a screen shot instead of text to make it obvious that is an screen output. That is not code or anything useful that could require a cut and paste. If I only had pasted the text, it would have prevent the user to see quickly it is a screen output (cmd line output). Does it still appear that I should have used pasted text?

Answer (score 0):

I just found my solution. The sample can't be run as is; it should be included into a console application. The problem arise when you take the code and include it into a Windows application (any, like a [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) application). When you do so, Console.ReadLine will not stop waiting for the user to press "Enter" like in a console app because the standard input device for a Windows application is not the keyboard. See documentation: [Console.ReadLine Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Console.ReadLine)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-6.0)

> 'If the standard input device is the keyboard, the ReadLine method
> blocks until the user presses the Enter key.'

But it does not stop and wait in a Windows application.